# Publishing on IIS angular 2 app with .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, iis, publish, node-modules

I have set up an angular 2 app with mvc.
I am using typescript 2.3.1.0 for visual studio.
I installed the node modules and added reference to angular 2.

Views -> Home -> Index file -

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Angular 2 QuickStart</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- Angular2 Code -->
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
        <!-- Angular2 Code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And I added all the references to my Views -> Shared -> Layout file -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="118134028665-i6h833e7irrrhk0n52bgj7ve6fet4vgr.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <!-- Angular2 Code -->
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
    <!-- Angular2 Code -->

</head>
<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/JS/SocialLogin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This is my package.json file -

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings":"^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

This is my systemjs.config.js file -

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

When the node modules folder is not included in the project, it is build successfully and when I run it is working ok.

Once I publish it and move the publish to a dev server and deploy it on IIS the mvc runs but the angular 2 is not.
These are the errors that I get -

[image: Error of angular 2]

I assume that I get this errors since the node modules folder is missing.

If I go back to the project and include node modules in the project and build it I get these errors -

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Build:File
> 'E:/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp.Site/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/rx/ts/core/linq/observable/mergeproto.ts'
> not found.    MyApp.Site  E:\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.Site\tsc
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Build:File
> 'E:/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp.Site/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/rx/ts/core/linq/observable/zipproto.ts'
> not found.    MyApp.Site  E:\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.Site\tsc

How can I solve this issue?
What is the correct way to deploy angular 2 app with .net mvc on iis?
What is the right way to include the node modules in this project?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dina, I am facing same issue and not able to proceed further. Did you find any solution yet? please let me know if you found anything?

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced same issue and didn't got appropriate solution ,
So i have used another solution.

1. Deploy your MVC (API) on IIS independent.
2. Build your Angular 2 Application separately using `ng prod`.
3. Deploy Angular 2 Application means (dist folder) as a static website
       on IIS.
4. In Angular 2 API use deployed API for data access.

If you get any error ping me.